# \documentclass{article}: show author's position

Tags: article

My Latex code is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\author{Author}
\title{Title}
\maketitle
Document's text.
\end{document}
```

The output is:
[image]

How can I show the author's position underneath the author's name, e.g. Professor at ...?

Comment: The standard `article` class has no further fields. But you can write something like `\author{Author\\Some University}`.

Comment: @gernot Do you want to make that an answer? Or do we have a good duplicate that suits?

Comment: @Johannes_B I decided to do both since none of the other posts deals with the simple case of a single author; but there are similar posts. Thanks for reviewing the post.

Answer (score 5):

The standard `article` class has no further fields. But you can put additional information into the `\author` command, like

```
\author{Author\\Some University}
```

which will result in

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\author{Author\\Some University}
\title{Title}
\maketitle
Document's text.
\end{document}
```

For more complicated arrangements of multiple authors with mixed affiliations consider to use the [package `authblk`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/authblk).